# How/Do you reference your work here on LinkedIn?

Tags: discussion

I'd love to reference my work here on my LinkedIn profile, and I was wondering how people do that, if they do.

Organizations? Volunteer work? Other?

Should we provide guidance for others to attempt to make it consistent across LinkedIn profiles?

Comment: All our efforts pale before the onslaught of the bears...

Answer (score 6):

I agree completely with @RoryAlsop's answer.

However, I would also like to propose another solution - under "Websites", I have a link I labeled "Portfolio", which points to my [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) profile.

The advantage of pointing to a Careers profile, instead of straight to Sec.SE, is that it allows me to highlight the posts any way I want, and also include posts from other sites (e.g. the [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag on StackOverflow from before Sec.SE...).
This really allows you to build a portfolio of your "work", since so much of what we do is not "showable" (even as much as code). 
As @Rory says, an interviewer can use it to get an idea of what I am like, and I can use Careers.SO to focus them on what I want them to focus on.

Comment: Oooh - good idea. I have a Careers 2.0 profile, but hadn't linked to it.

Answer (score 3):

I do list out most of the activities I do on LinkedIn, including StackExchange, committee work and volunteer work, and it is a useful discussion point when talking to both potential employers, but also when hiring staff, as broadening the CV out from just the core work helps provide a more rounded picture of an individual.

Admittedly my Sec.SE stuff is from the perspective of a moderator, so I have this on my [LinkedIn profile](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=3402893):

> **Moderator**
>
> security.stackexchange.com January 2011 – Present (2 years 2
>   months)
>
> I am one of four moderators of the global security
>   question and answer site, which is part of the wider Stack Exchange
>   family of Q&A sites. I also administer the associated security blog at
>   security.blogoverflow.com
>
> From August 2012, I have also moderated the Personal Productivity
>   Stack Exchange site.

But to be honest, the discussion is usually around what Sec.SE does, not really what the moderator role is. When I am interviewing individuals, I like to see things like member/contributor to OWASP/SE/ISACA/BCS/ISF etc as it gives me another avenue of discussion to delve into what someone is like - and then also gives me a chance to quickly look through some of the stuff the have answered (in the case of Sec.SE) and understand their approach and whether they will fit into my team.

In terms of guidance - you could summarise specialisations (in the form of your top tags, perhaps) but I wouldn't make it the core focus of a CV - ideally this should have work experience or research (or courses if you are a student or new graduate)